# Recommended way to "join" dynamodb table with reference table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Let's say I got a table in dynamodb called visits which represents websites visits and one of the columns is the location.

In an RDBMS I would have:

```
visits [id, website_id, ........, location_id ]
ref_locations [id, city, country, postcode, lat, long]
```

The query we want to do is get me all the visits for this website (so by website id is fine) but I need the location information per visit. Like the city, the country etc. In Sql this is done with a simple join.

What about DynamoDB? I m thinking that we could store the location as a document in the table (hence denormalizing it completely) but I m sure this isn't the right way.

What do you guys do in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denormalization is one viable approach.  An alternative is to persist the reference table in Dynamo and then cache it in a local data structure (e.g. a Java/C#/Python/whatever `Map`) or in an in-memory key-value store (e.g. [Redis](http://redis.io/)).  Denormalization is preferable if the reference data is small and is (almost) completely static (since updates to denormalized data are extremely expensive), whereas caching is preferable if the reference data is moderately large and/or may be updated (in the latter case I recommend using a shared cache such as `Redis` instead of a per-server data structure as this will make it easier to invalidate/update the cache).  (If the reference data is large then you're probably best off just doing a second Dynamo fetch for it, but it doesn't sound like this is the case for your data.)

Regardless of which approach you choose, I suggest comparing benchmarks of storing the reference data as structured data or as a compressed binary - in my experience the reduced storage and network costs of compression are often worth the cpu costs of a g(un)zip (however my experience has primarily been with caching JSON or XML, which get good compression).